# Firebase Simulated and actual rules differ

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, polymerfire

I am using firebase realtime database and query data with `firebase-query` and `firebase-document`. I configured some rules, when ran in simulator the read is accepted but in real life read id denied. Have to `".read": true` in root to get expected outcome. **Note:** i am using both `polymerfire` AND Firebase js sdk but for different things and JS is on external file and I am writing rules using Bolt compiler.

**rules**:

rules.bolt

```
 //Questions
 path /Question/{qid} {
  read() { true }
  write() { true}
 }

 //Users
 path /Users/{uid}/Profile {
  read() { true }
  write() { signedIn() && isUser(auth, uid) }
 }

 path /Users/{uid}/Metadata {
  read() { signedIn() && isUser(auth, uid) }
  write() { signedIn() && isUser(auth, uid) }
 }

 function signedIn (){ auth != null}

 function isUser (auth, userKey) {
  return auth.uid == userKey;
 }
```

rules.json

```
{
  "rules": {
    "Question": {
      "$qid": {
        ".read": "true",
        ".write": "true"
      }
    },
    "Users": {
      "$uid": {
        "Profile": {
          ".read": "true",
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        },
        "Metadata": {
          ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
          ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EXPECTATION**

Stored value is initialised and the data can only be read from `Questons/{{qid}}` and `Users/{{uid}}/Profile` (and `Users/{{uid}}/Metadata` if the user is seeing him/hers won profile) and all the data is shown.

**REALITY**

When not used `".read": true`:

```
Initializing stored value.
```

and no data is incoming **though** when ran in simulator read is granted.

When USED `".read": true`:

```
Initializing stored value.
  Sync to memory.
  Updating data from Firebase value: {Metadata: {…}, Profile: {…}}
  Got stored value! {Metadata: {…}, Profile: {…}} {Metadata: {…}, 
  Profile: {…}}
Sync to memory.
```

and other datas are also incoming and are showing.

**I think** this is because of rules cascade.

If rules cascade is the case how to fix this up using Bolt and if not then what to do?

Comment: Instead of sharing screenshots of your app, share the minimal code and the error message you get as text.

Comment: did it and placed console logs

Comment: Please also add the code that triggers this output. I recommend reading this page about [creating a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn about what an MCVE is, why it's useful for you to create one.